# <string> and 'string' difference in Kohana

Tags: php, kohana

I'm new with Kohana and I've already watched one video tutorial. And just started to read book "Kohana 3.0, Beginner's Guide". In video tutorial tutor uses

```
    View::factory('template_name')
```

but in the book, author uses

```
    View::factory(<template_name>)
```

this < template_name > is it PHP feature or Kohana's? And what's the difference between quoted and inequality-ated names?

Comment: `<template_name>` is just a placeholder for a variable or string literal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<template_name>` is a convention meaning "insert your template name here." It is not valid PHP code until you insert your template name as a string.

For further information, check the introduction of the book: you will likely find a list of conventions used by the author and an explanation of each.

Comment: Oops.. After this I've checked errata of the book, and it was mistype... It looks like book have a lot errors...